# Passing model objects from one view controller to another in a navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have two UITableViewControllers. One displays a list of names and on tapping any cell will push the second TableViewController which enables the user to edit the name in a UITextField.

Now I am able to pass the name string from the first TableViewController to the second. (I'm doing this by creating a property in the second TableViewController which I'm setting just before pushing the second TableViewController) But how do I pass the edited name string from the second to the first (so that I can update the first table with the edited name)?

Comment: Thanks you all for your inputs. However I'm trying to implement a solution similar to what Rayfleck has suggested. However it doesnt seem to work. The cell in the first table is not updated when it shows again. (I am reloading the cell at that indexPath). What might I be missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mutable array property in the first controller, and pass that array and an index to the second controller.

FirstController.h

```
   @property (nonatomic,retain)     NSMutableArray *myStrings;
```

FirstController.m

```
   @synthesize myStrings;

   init {
         self.myStrings = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
   }


   didSelectRowAtIndexPath {

     SecondVC *vc = [[SecondVC new];
     [self.theStrings addObject:@"Original String"]; // or replaceAtIndex: indexPath.row
     vc.theStrings = self.myStrings;
     vc.theIndex   = indexPath.row;
     //push detail vc.
   }
```

SecondController.h

```
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *theStrings;
  @property (nonatomic        ) int             theIndex;
```

SecondController.m

```
  @synthesize theStrings;
  @synthesize theIndex;

  doneEditingMethod {
       [self.theStrings replaceObjectAtIndex: self.theIndex withObject: myNewString];
   }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying but it doesnt update the first table when it shows again !!

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper - my apologies.  I've updated the post using a mutable array and an index.  This assumes you have pre-populated the array with values - basically whatever your data source is.

Answer (score 2):

I see mainly three options:

1. you could define your model as a singleton, which is easily accessible from every other object. In this case think about concurrent access to the model, it any;
2. have the model private to the first controller, but instead of passing the string to the second controller, pass a pointer to the model, so you can read and write to it;
3. pass the second controller a pointer to the first, so you can signal it (by calling some specific method); this is ok if you subclass the controller, otherwise you should use a delegate.

A fourth option would be using notifications, but I think that 1 or 2 a the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at the delegate pattern which could save you a lot of time ! :-)

You know it's like using an UITableView datasource. With a delegate (or datasource), you can ask or set informations to a root controller.

Maybe it's the best option !
(so google "objective-c delegate")

Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

Are they connected by a navigation controller?

If so, this could solve the problem

```
// in SecondViewController.m
NSArray* controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UITableViewController* firstViewController = [controllers objectAtIndex:controllers.count-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I, personally, use a third-party class to house strings and just reference that class as I move between UITableViews.