# Passing control between two views in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing model objects from one view controller to another in a navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231484/passing-model-objects-from-one-view-controller-to-another-in-a-navigation-stack)

I am trying to pass the control between two views in iphone. I have tried this and it works fine when you pass from the first view controller to the second but when i click the second, it blanks out. Why is that so? Any help is appreciated.. Thanks...

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2nd.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;

}
-(IBAction)passdata:(id)sender;

@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2nd.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void) changeLabel:(NSString*)str{
    lbl.text = @"Hello";
}

-(IBAction)passdata:(id)sender{
    ViewController2nd *second = [[ViewController2nd alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:^{ }];
}

@end
```

ViewController2nd.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void) changeLabel:(NSString*)str;
@end

@interface ViewController2nd : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIButton *bttn;

}

-(IBAction)bttnclicked;
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController2nd.m

```
#import "ViewController2nd.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2nd ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2nd

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)bttnclicked{

}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender{
    ViewController *first = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentmodalViewController:first animated:YES completion:^{ }];
}

@end
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: why you are presenting the first viewcontroller from the second ?

Comment: On back method, are you creating a new object for first or you wanted to go back to the previous object? and when is the issue happening?

Comment: Search properly on net you will not need to post this question.

Comment: so that he can go back to the first view.... to and forth?

Comment: I watched a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4zmM_Rqv6Y&list=UU6-UA1FoMnbO2LCLWPCM9aA&index=18&feature=plcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to go to the first view change the `back:` method like:

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
 {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```

Don't display the parentView as the childView of the chilkdViewController. It also makes memory issues and logical issues.

So if you want to go from the childView to parentView, dismiss the childView and never create the parent object and present it there.

Comment: what in the case, i would like to a third view, then i should use the same code with the link to the third view and am i right?

Comment: then it's ok, but if the user presses the button again, it will show the second view again and so on, it can cause a crash due to memory. That's why it is not a good implementation.